# Customize Controls for All Items on Canvas

Tags: fabricjs

In the Customization portion of the fabric.js documentation (http://fabricjs.com/customization/) it points out numerous ways to modify the look and feel of the borders for certain items on the canvas. The syntax used is:

```
canvas.item(0).hasControls = false;
```

Or:

```
canvas.item(0).hasControls = canvas.item(0).hasBorders = false;
```

Etc. Is there a way to use the hasControls/hasBorders customization on *all* items on the canvas, without having to call them out by item number?

I've tried:

```
canvas.hasControls = false;
canvas.hasBorders = false;
```

But that doesn't have any effect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you can do:

```
canvas.forEachObject(function(o){ o.hasBorders = o.hasControls = false; });
```

Or you can change the object prototype defaults from the beginning, right after initializing the canvas:

```
fabric.Object.prototype.hasControls = false;
fabric.Object.prototype.hasBorders = false;
```